# Margin issue while viewing in mobile

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, web, padding

I have corrected all of my pages so that they look good while viewing in mobile (iphone) but I have one page that didn't turn out well.

This is the page I am looking to fix up so that the images are presented better.
http://www.jobspark.ca/read-me/

Here is a screenshot that demonstrates how the images get pushed when page is resized smaller. Looking to fix this with CSS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use media queries, or a responsive framework that alters your elements' styles at a certain "breakpoint". Short-term solution, adding something like this to your CSS file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
img { width:100%; height:auto; clear:both; }
}
```

This means that when your page is viewed in a window with a width of less than 767px, the img will be displayed on a line all by itself, and its width will expand to occupy the entire container. This will not work as is if your images are within divs (within divs).

For future reference, look into media queries and responsive grid-based frameworks, they'll do all the heavy lifting for you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries

Frameworks:
Skeleton: http://getskeleton.com/
Unsemantic: http://unsemantic.com/

Comment: Hmmm didnt seem to work. It changed my website logo but not the images on that page. I will keep trying here

Comment: Yea I was messing around with some CSS rules in firefox but couldn't get it to jive either. Probably something to do with the use of inline styles or multitude of divs encompassing each image. :/ Sorry I couldn't be of more help.